# Optimizing the R MICE imputation

Tags: r, arraylist, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to make sense of a number of data files I got from world bank data, but the first problem I faced was the incredible number of missing data points. I cam across the concept of multiple imputation, and was even able to use it to some extent, but it is far from perfect. First of all, all the data points that are originally present are strict percentages, but the imputation does not seem to take that into account. I assumed that if I increase the number of imputations and number of iterations, the error would diminish, but that approach seem to be taking incredible amount of time. Here is the code I am using right now-

```
require("tools")      #Load required packages
require("dplyr")
require("mice")


dataFileNames <- as.data.frame(file_path_sans_ext(list.files("Data/")))   #Extract file names
dataFileNames <- rename(dataFileNames,"fileName"='file_path_sans_ext(list.files("Data/"))') #Rename the column in the vector
dataFileNames$fileName <- as.character(dataFileNames$fileName)  #Convert into characters

Fetch_Data <- function(Filename){

  dataName <- paste("Data/",Filename,sep = "")

  rawData <- read.csv(unz(paste(dataName,".zip",sep = ""),paste(Filename,".csv",sep = "")),skip = 4,header = TRUE)
  dataName <- as.character(rawData[1,3])
  return(list(rawData,dataName))
  return(rawData)
}   #UDF 1: Fetch data from the csvs within the zip files




dataList <- list()  #Create an empty list to fill in

for(i in 1:nrow(dataFileNames)){
  dataList[[i]] <- assign(Fetch_Data(dataFileNames[i,1])[[2]],Fetch_Data(dataFileNames[i,1])[[1]])

}  #Fill in the list with data

FinalData <- bind_rows(dataList)  #Join all data by row

countryNames <- as.data.frame(unique(FinalData$Country.Name)) #List Country Names
countryNames <- rename(countryNames,List.of.Countries='unique(FinalData$Country.Name)')  #Rename header properly
indicatorNames <- as.data.frame(unique(FinalData$Indicator.Name))  #List Indicators
indicatorNames <- rename(indicatorNames,List.of.Indicators='unique(FinalData$Indicator.Name)')  #Rename header properly


binnedByCountry <- split(FinalData,FinalData$Country.Name)  #Create a list with data binned by country
binnedByVariable <- split(FinalData,FinalData$Indicator.Name) #Create a list with data binned by indicator


# binnedByCountry <- lapply(binnedByCountry, function(x)x[!(names(x) %in% c("Country.Name","Indicator.Code","Country.Code","X"))]) #Remove redundant columns
# binnedByVariable <- lapply(binnedByVariable, function(x)x[!(names(x) %in% c("Indicator.Name","Country.Code","Indicator.Code","X"))]) #Remove redundant column


Impute_Data <- function(dataValue,MAXITS,IMPS){
  imputation <- mice(dataValue, seed=1, maxit = MAXITS, m=IMPS)
  predM = imputation$predictorMatrix
  meth=imputation$method
  predM[,c("Country.Name")]=0
  predM[,c("Country.Code")]=0
  predM[,c("Indicator.Name")]=0
  predM[,c("Indicator.Code")]=0

  filledInData <- complete(imputation)
  return(filledInData)

}   #UDF 2:Impute data with MAXITS iterations and IMPS imputations

rm(list=setdiff(ls(),c("FinalData","Fetch_Data","binnedByCountry","binnedByVariable","Impute_Data")))  #Remove unwanted variables from global environment

Results <- Impute_Data(FinalData,1,1)
```

When I ran the imputation function on the data formatted as list,

```
lapply(binnedByCountry,Impute_Data)
```

It was relatively fast, but it would stop in between when it detected too many missing data. Only after that approach did I put in the additional arguments of MAXITS and IMPS. 
As it stands now, for each iteration the whole thing takes around 15-20 minutes, so I need to optimize the code before hoping to get a much more representative result. On the other hand, if there are more restrictions I can put on the mice imputations, that would be welcome too. My ultimate goal is to runs some regression tests on the thus received values, and get some inference out of them. Any suggestion as to how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure people here would love to help, and you have a very good question, but it's not __reproducible__. All the code up until your `ImputeData` function is no use to anyone. We can't access your computer. Where does `FetchData` come from? It's not a standard R function.

Comment: Regarding the actual imputations, the `mice` function has a number of "methods" for imputation. These can be specified for each column of the data frame via the `method` argument, the default being "pmm" of predictive mean matching. There are also methods for binary and categorical (ordered or unordered) variables. I am not sure about strict proportions (values between 0 and 1) but there is the option of writing your own imputation method.